# QtCreator debugger does not display values of std::string

Tags: c++, gdb, qt-creator

I tried to debug my small little lexer and ran into this problem: the QtCreator-Debugger does not display any content of my std::string-variable. I tried to debug it in console and I got the same result, just plain structure information.

The version of QtCreator I used a few days ago did display the content of the strings. All other STL-Elements like std::vector, std::map, std::multimap, etc. display the correct data, it's just the std::string class which does not do the right.

After several hours of googling I found a lot of web pages which describe the creation of pretty printers, my really noobish approaches to fix this didn't help. Any ideas how I can get rid of this bug?

Note: The 'content' of the string-variables will always be displayed as 'not accessible'.
      I use QtCreator 2.6 (QT5) for 64bit Linux OS.

Edit(1): I reinstalled everything from OS to Compilers and IDE... The strange is, when I build my project with optimization level 3 (-O3) QT can display std::strings.

The command line is the following:
clang++ -std=c++11 -O3 -g -c foo.cpp

When I remove -O3 std::strings are < not accessible >. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to build g++ from source, or obtain libstdc++-debug
package for your distribution.

Comment: I ran into another problem now, gdb does not recognize anything anymore... It just says '/usr/lib/.../libstdc++.so.6.0.16-gdb.py' is not found, but it exists?!? I will reinstall my OS now...

Comment: Might be a known issue with Qtcreator when using gcc-9;
see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-22680 & https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-22753

Comment: This problem seem to like revisiting us.

Answer (score 11):

You can try to fix "/usr/share/qtcreator/debugger/stdtypes.py". As they use "hard-code assumption on member position" it seems like not working everywhere.
In my case - Linux x64, gcc 9.1 it works exactly like you described:
 [string not accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlJTp.png)

So find function `def qdumpHelper_std__string(d, value, charType, format):`

And change 
`(size, alloc, refcount) = d.split("ppp", data - 3 * d.ptrSize())` 
to 
`(size, alloc, refcount) = d.split("ppp", value.address() + d.ptrSize())`

Also comment `d.check(0 <= size and size <= alloc and alloc <= 100*1000*1000)` or change it to something like

```
if size > 1000:
   size = 1000
```

On my system std::string has next structure

```
pointer 8 byte
size    8 byte
union   16 byte
```

And this `union` field can change its meaning depends on string size. So we need to comment that `size < alloc` check.
`value.address()` - the address of the string object, so `value.address() + d.ptrSize()`will point to size, and `value.address() + 2 * d.ptrSize()` point to that union, which contain `alloc size` value, from time to time.

Just look at your `std::string` class declaration so you will get structure on your system.
And after the fix:
[fixed debuger view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezPw4.png)

Works both - when "system GDB pretty printers" checked and clear

Comment: Oh boy, this solved my issue with the latest Manjaro. I'm using gdb 8.3 and gcc 9.1.0 here with QtCreator 4.9.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I made a patch: https://pastebin.com/s5QBMGHQ.

Using: sudo patch /opt/qtcreator-4.10.2/share/qtcreator/debugger/stdtypes.py stdtypes.py.patch

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it worked for me. 
In Qt Creator menu bar:

```
Tools -> Options -> Debugger
Uncheck the option (Load system GDB pretty printers)
```

Answer (score 3):

To clarify and sum up AstoBasto post:
In file: /usr/share/qtcreator/debugger/stdtypes.py replace this function:

```
def qdumpHelper_std__string(d, value, charType, format):
[...]
```

With this:

```
def qdumpHelper_std__string(d, value, charType, format):
if d.isQnxTarget():
    qdumpHelper__std__string__QNX(d, value, charType, format)
    return
if d.isMsvcTarget():
    qdumpHelper__std__string__MSVC(d, value, charType, format)
    return

data = value.extractPointer()
# We can't lookup the std::string::_Rep type without crashing LLDB,
# so hard-code assumption on member position
# struct { size_type _M_length, size_type _M_capacity, int _M_refcount; }

(size, alloc, refcount) = d.split("ppp", value.address() + d.ptrSize())
refcount = refcount & 0xffffffff
d.check(refcount >= -1) # Can be -1 according to docs.

if size > 4002:
    size = 4002
d.putCharArrayHelper(data, size, charType, format)
```

And this works (at least on Kubuntu 19.10).